# import/export error - magento 2.0.1

Tags: magento2, admin, import, importexport, export

Firstly I export csv file from admin and keep only one row and delete the remaining row, after that I will change product name,category name and then import the file.I am getting the result in frontend. Similarly update the 52 rows of new category and product name, now stuck with one error

```
1. Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

**note:** here I am not upload image folder because I dont want to change image, in csv I just change product name and category.

I have checked file permission, its fine (755).

check data also give success message, import only the problem. I think its minor fix.

anything I did wrong? how to solve the issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: yes @CarlOwens. comment your issue if I know I will help you.

Comment: I figured it out.  Turns out the php memory limit was 256mb.  Updated it to 2048mb and the import worked fine.  There is no real error shown for this in magento 2.  Logged the exception as per (https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1099) and discovered the issue.

Comment: great @CarlOwens. do you mean you can get same error what I get. You can resolved with php memory limit am I right.

Comment: Yes I got the same error but it was due to php's memory limit within the php.ini config.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First time I had success because I set **Allowed Error Counts to 10** while importing. My CSV file has only one row so it skipped the one error, Updated the details except image.

Second time I got an error because I have more than 10 rows.

**Reason:**

While importing, magento looks at images in the **pub/media/import** folder, but I left it as empty so instead it will throw the error I previously mentioned. After copying the image into **pub/media/import** my problem got solved.

**note:** suppose you need to change product name only, just remove the all the image value(leave as empty, don't need to mention the image URL).

Comment: Hmm this solution did not work in my case

Answer (score 2):

For the import images issue i have fixed the issue from `Uploader.php` file. change below file path code and success working import images.

> File path:
>   magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Uploader.php

```
Find the below line from line number 201:
```

> $filePath = $this->_directory->getRelativePath($filePath . $fileName);

```
Replace with:
```

> $filePath = strpos($filePath, $fileName) !== false ?
>   $filePath:$this->_directory->getRelativePath($filePath . $fileName);

**For More information Refer github link:**

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/20761/commits/8612789375b0c173f0ba852c587882af6ff8bc7f

Comment: I tried the above code in my localhost but still, I get the same error. So please give me a solution.

Comment: Have you checked your CSV format it is proper or not.

Comment: Yes csv proper on click and check It is perfect, Then after when click to import then this issue comes. I will fetch Image from https://ik.imagekit.io/bfrs/tr:w-auto,h-auto,pr-true,c-at_max:cm-pad_extract,w-auto,h-auto,bg-FFFFFF/image_artloungein/data/1214242.jpg

Comment: Have you added that images individual full path to image field?

Comment: yes I added already

Comment: Also check CSV format should be comma separated.

Comment: Now I added another image URL from google and tried then direct imported but that server URL not imported,Is there any issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99338/discussion-between-kirti-nariya-and-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel).

Answer (score 1):

run the below commands on the magento root directory.

`find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while trying to import 250 products with images. The fix for me was to remove any spacial charecter from the file name not even comma or space anywhere in the image name. example - LCDwithTouchScreenforSamsungGalaxyS7edgeCDMABlackcompleteassemblyfolder.jpg and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.
I solved renaming the directories, they had uppercase and lowercase
(A-a) (B-b) (C-c) Etc..etc ..
I set everything in lowercase, you must also check the CSV that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

here is what helped me.
look for path of php.ini file : php --ini
change memory_limit to 2G in the php.ini file
rename all images to image_*.JPG