# Default uploading image size in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-images, image-upload

I met one strange issue in Magento 2 - I’m trying to change default uploading image size from `800x1200` to `934x1400`.

I modified `view.xml` and now uploaded images going straight to folder `media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/934x1400/`

```
<image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
                <width>934</width>
                <height>1400</height>
</image>
<image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image">
                <width>934</width>
                <height>1400</height>
</image>
<image id="product_page_image_large" type="image">
                <width>934</width><!-- 800 -->
                <height>1400</height><!-- 1090 -->
</image>
<image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
                <width>934</width><!-- 800 -->
                <height>1400</height><!-- 1090 -->
</image>
```

But their actual size is still `800x1200`

Any ideas how to solve this issue? I can’t find any settings to modify default uploading image size.

Comment: Can you show your change to view.xml?

Comment: `<image id="product_page_main_image" type="image">
    <width>934</width>
    <height>1400</height>
</image>
<image id="product_page_main_image_default" type="image">
    <width>934</width>
    <height>1400</height>
</image>
<image id="product_page_image_large" type="image">
    <width>934</width><!-- 800 -->
    <height>1400</height><!-- 1090 -->
</image>
<image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
    <width>934</width><!-- 800 -->
    <height>1400</height><!-- 1090 -->
</image>`

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13747

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to change max resizing width & height of the image after uploading:

1) `Magento\Framework\File\Uploader.php` contain constants `MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT` & `MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH` which is set to 1200 by default

2) `magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/media/uploader.phtml` contains PHP code for echo same constants `MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT` and `MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH`. You can just hardcode your value instead these values.

Comment: Did you succeed overwide the Magento\Framework\File\Uploader.php class ?

Comment: I made module for this: https://bitbucket.org/fred_imgmedia/imageproccess

Comment: For information your module do not manage all cases. Check my answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126420/how-do-i-change-or-off-in-backend-for-uploading-image-default-max-width/146905#146905 . Why do you not use your constant of your Uploader class inside template ?

Comment: Can you update your answer with these locations : `vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/templates/browser/content/uploader.phtml:103` `vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/media/uploader.phtml:17`  `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/adminhtml/web/js/variations/steps/bulk.js:317`

Comment: In the newest versions of Magento, you can navigate to Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Images Upload Configuration in admin panel. There you will see the settings and you don't need a module anymore to override this

Answer (score 3):

**Some clarification:**

The upload image size limitation is done in multiple area :

**Upload images on configurable product creation steps:**

```
vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/adminhtml/web/js/variations/steps/bulk.js:317
```

**Upload image for a product**

```
vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/media/uploader.phtml:17
```

**Upload image for CMS**

```
vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/templates/browser/content/uploader.phtml:103
```

**Abstract class with the constant value**

```
vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php:138
```

To my mind Magento has not finished to implement correctly this feature because the value is harcoded for the configurable creation.