# Product image uploading issue from external path magento 2?

Tags: product-images, csv, magento-2.1.8

I am uploading images from an external URL. Image uploaded in the dir but getting an error message:

```
1. Imported resource (image) could not be downloaded from external resource due to timeout or access permissions in row(s): 1
```

Comment: Please refer this solution it works for me. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109135/import-export-error-magento-2-0-1

Comment: I have increased memory_limit 1G, but still, the issue is same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Magento older version, Image import using external URL feature available in Magento Open Source 2.2.x.

Please check link [Magento Open Source 2.2.x](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import-product-images.html)

Comment: I am using Magento 2.1.8

Comment: sorry so it' not working in your version, if you would like to use that functionality then you have to override default functionality method and use your custom code.